# Can I install my own VPN software on my AWS Windows instance instead of using Amazon's?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vpn-client

I would like to employ a VPN on my public AWS instance for security. I see that AWS offers several solutions for this but they all carry the usual EC2/hr costs which add up to quite a lot over a year based on my usage of 25 users.

Why would I need/want to use a "bundled" VPN solution from AWS as opposed to simply installing a copy of SoftEther or OpenVPN and configuring it on the server to use as I would any other physical server I was administering?

My goal is to install SoftEther on my AWS Windows server and avoid all of the managed costs associated with AWS Client VPN or the like.

Am I missing something that precludes me from approaching it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can install almost anything you like on AWS virtual servers, other than virtualization software. There should be no problem putting whatever software VPN client you prefer onto your instance.

The advantage of using AWS managed service is they're high performance (typically 1.25Gbps), have redundant connectivity (two tunnels), and fully managed, which means AWS will fix it if it breaks. AWS managed connections may occasionally be taken down for maintenance, but only one of the two tunnels at at time.